# Placement new for MCU register abstraction proposed by Meyers

Tags: c++, embedded, placement-new

I just tried to use a placement new operator as suggested by Scott Meyers in "Effectice C++ in an Embedded Environment".

```
    DefaultMcuType::PortRegister* p = new(reinterpret_cast<void*>(0x05)) DefaultMcuType::PortRegister;
```

Then I get the follwoing errors:

```
register.cc: In function 'int main()':
register.cc:30:90: error: no matching function for call to 'operator     new(sizetype, void*)'
 DefaultMcuType::PortRegister* p = new(reinterpret_cast<void*>(0x05))  DefaultMcuType::PortRegister;
                                                                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
<built-in>: note: candidate: void* operator new(unsigned int)
<built-in>: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
<built-in>: note: candidate: void* operator new(unsigned int,  std::align_val_t)
<built-in>: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'void*' to  'std::align_val_t'
register.cc:30:35: warning: unused variable 'p' [-Wunused-variable]
 DefaultMcuType::PortRegister* p = new(reinterpret_cast<void*>(0x05))    DefaultMcuType::PortRegister;
                               ^
```

I really can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You are missing `#include <new>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Placement new is an operator function.
Your specific one should be defined as

`void* operator new  ( std::size_t count, void* ptr );`

in the header file `<new>`.

Using `#include <new>` should resolve your problem.

For an example see here:
https://godbolt.org/g/iKatox

More information about the new operators can be found here:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new

---

Update:

If you don't have access to placement new you might define it yourself.
I used the VC++14 version as a template for this:

```
#include <stdlib.h> //for std::size_t
inline void* operator new(std::size_t size, void* ptr)
{
  (void)size;//unused
  return ptr;
}

inline void operator delete(void*, void*)
{
  return;
}
```

You can compare both versions generating the same assembly code:
https://godbolt.org/g/6UjER9

Comment: Well, what should I do, if I don't have a <new> include file, as it is the case with avr-g++?